# The if statement doesn't work for false in php

Tags: php, if-statement

When trying to get familiar with `if` statement in PHP, this happened.
First time i tried this code below.

```
if(true) {echo 'true';} else {echo 'false';}
```

And the output was `true` when the condition is `true`. Again, when the condition is `false` (`if(false)`) it echos `false`.

But i tried the same, using a variable as the condition, while changing the value of the variable.

```
$con='false';
if($con){echo 'true';} else{echo 'false';}
```

At this situation the output is `true` even when the variable value is `false` or `true`. At the same time, the `if statement` working fine when `1` and `0` is used instead `true` and `false`.  Why is this happening?

Comment: So.. many.. answers :O

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP does some sneaky things in the if expression. The following values are considered FALSE:

- the boolean FALSE itself
- the integer 0 (zero)
- the float 0.0 (zero)
- the empty string, and the string "0"
- an array with zero elements
- an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
- the special type NULL (including unset variables)
- SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).

You're actually passing a string that says the word false, rather than the value false itself. Because that isn't in the above list, it is actually considered true!

Answer (score 10):

```
$con='false';
```

That `'false'` is a valid string which is not Boolean `FALSE`, just like `$con='hi';` isn't.

```
$con=FALSE;  //this is false now
```

To quote from the **[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)**

> To specify a boolean literal, use the constants TRUE or FALSE. Both are case-insensitive.

Also read these other options that you have

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> ◦  the boolean FALSE itself
> ◦  the integer 0 (zero)
> ◦  the float 0.0 (zero)
> ◦  the empty string, and the string "0"
> ◦  an array with zero elements
> ◦  an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> ◦  the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> ◦ SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

Then you observed this

> At the same time, the if statement working fine when 1 and 0 is used instead true and false. Why is this happening?

This is because 0 in any form is FALSE, either string or numeric. But the text `false` as a string is not false for reasons mentioned above.

Also read about PHP **[Strict Comparisons](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)** since you're learning, because

```
var_dump(0==FALSE);    //bool(true)
var_dump(0===FALSE);   //bool(false)   :)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a bool instead of a string:

```
$con = false;
```

Your if statement will simply check that $con is not empty, so in your example it will always be true.

Comment: "Since PHP 5.3"? Nothing has changed about boolean comparison in such recent history.

Comment: @deceze I thought that PHP checking if a string was empty like this was brought in on PHP 5.3, I'll take it out to remove any confusion anyway.

Answer (score 3):

> As described in the section about expressions, expression is evaluated to its Boolean value. If expression evaluates to TRUE, PHP will execute statement, and if it evaluates to FALSE - it'll ignore it. More information about what values evaluate to FALSE can be found in the [**'Converting to boolean'**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) section.

So as per docs try using

```
$con = false;//boolean and not a string
if($con){echo 'true';} else{echo 'false';}
```

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> ◦  the boolean FALSE itself
>   ◦  the integer 0 (zero)
>   ◦  the float 0.0 (zero)
>   ◦  the empty string, and the string "0"
>   ◦  an array with zero elements
>   ◦  an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
>   ◦  the special type NULL (including unset variables)
>   ◦ SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

[**Check Docs (IF MANUAL)**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Answer (score 3):

You are using 'false' as a **STRING** variable, but that is the WORD false, not the **BOOLEAN** constant. Just use **false**

```
if(true) {echo 'true';} else {echo 'false';}

$con='false';  // Wrong
$con=false; // Right
if($con){echo 'true';} else{echo 'false';}
```

And when you are doing if statements, this will work:

```
if ($con == false) { echo 'false'; }
```

or you can use a === which compares one expression to another by value and by type.

```
if ($con === false) { echo 'false with type safe comparison!'; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign value to variable like this

```
$con=false;
```

Answer (score 2):

`'false'` is not same as `false`.

`if('true')` or `if('false')` will result `true` always as they will be treated as `string`s and will be converted for comparison.

```
$con=false;
if($con){echo 'true';} else{echo 'false';}
```

Will print `false`

Answer (score 2):

In your second example, `$con` isn't the boolean `false`, it's a **string literal** `'false'` (note the quotes), and any non-empty string in PHP evaluates as `true`.

To fix this, just drop the quotes:

```
$con=false; // no quotes!
if($con){echo 'true';} else{echo 'false';}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your $con declaration is a string not a bool. So it will always return true. 
To declare a boolean, use:

```
$con=FALSE;  //or TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

change the value of your variable to this

```
   $con = false;
```